# CanCan Ability Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I have a Rails 4 app that i wrote a CanCan Ability model for based on my model setup in my app. While testing it works sometimes and then it doesn't. Im not sure what the problem is. There is nothing in the logs that would point to a problem. I also don't think that it is that clean anyway. Any suggestions on how to improve this Ability model? It seems very redundant and confusing.

```
if user
      ##
      can :manage, User do |u|
        case u.account
          ## If user is a Developer allow it to only be managed by itself (user)
          when Developer
            u == user
          ## If user is a Organization allow it to only be managed by it's founders
          when Organization
            u.account.founders.exists?(user)
          else
            false
        end
      end

      can :manage, App do |a|
        case a.appable
          ## If app belongs to a Developer allow it to only be managed by it owner (developer)
          when Developer
            a.appable.id == user.id
          ## If app belongs to a Organization allow it to only be managed by its organizations' founders
          when Organization
            a.appable.founders.exists?(user)
          else
            false
        end
      end
      ##
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for cleaning it up, you could consider instead organizing the logic by user role.  This way you can easily look at a given role and understand all the abilities that they do and do not have access to.

Something like this:

```
if user.developer?
  can :manage User, id: user.id
  can :manage App, App.appable_by(user) 
end
```

NOTE: you may need to write some custom finders like `App.appable_by(user)` in order to test the rule

I don't fully follow what you are trying to do with Organization / founders.  If this is a role like user.founder?  Then treat it like mentioned above, but with a different authorization rule.